# Foxit Reader : Remove Side Banners From Start Page

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

[Foxit Reader Side Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR3lo.png)

Rather than disabling the whole start page, is there a way to remove or edit the default banners (Phantom PDF & ISSUU) that appear besides the history list? I tried to change the images **issuu-bg.jpg** & **phantom_banner.jpg** but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too much efforts, found the solution

- For removing the ISSUU background image, go to 
  `C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Roaming\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\StartPage 9.7.2\start\en-US\custom\issuu` and edit **`issuu-bg.jpg`**.
- For removing the Phantom PDF background image, go `C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Roaming\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\StartPage 9.7.2\start\en-US\images` and edit **`phantom_banner.jpg`**

[This is what it looks like after editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJuR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to "File > Preferences > General" and uncheck "Show advertisement".

Comment: It's already unchecked!